# Best use of certification points in Planetside 2?

Tags: planetside-2

What is the most efficient way or most useful way to put in certification points? Weapons?
Vehicles? Are there any essential upgrades?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your playstyle.

Essential upgrades are:

- S-AMS for the Sunderer: 50 Certs
- Nanoweave or Flak for all classes: 1 cert for the first level, basically free

Recommended for organized play:

- Anti-Tank Mines for the Engineer: 100 Certs for level 1
- Scout Radar for the Flash: 50+100 Certs for the first 2 levels
- Anti-Air Lock-on launcher for the Heavy Assault: 725 Certs/700 SC (Alternatively Annihilator)
- Burster arm for the MAX: 1000 Certs/700 SC
- Skyguard for the Lightning: 1000 Certs/700 SC
- Mineguard for the Sunderer: 30+50 Certs for the first 2 levels
- Squad leader/Spawn beacon: 30 Certs
- Squad leader/Command channel: 100 Certs

Playstyle dependant:

- Rocket-Pods for ESF (Mosquito/Reaver/Scythe): 1000 Certs/700 SC
- HE or HEAT for the Lightning: 750 Certs/700 SC HE, 250 Certs/500 SC HEAT

In general, don't worry about wasting Certs. There is an infinite amount of Certs, so you will eventually unlock everything. Just try around, use the VR training area to trial stuff and if you unlock something and it turns out to be not your thing it's no big deal.

Comment: *"Mineguard for the Sunderer"* - as I understand it, the mineguard is not very effective, and even with the mineguard a direct hit (which is almost always) will still destroy the Sunderer in one hit

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Mineguard is extremely effective. Every level increases the amount of mines required to destroy the Sunderer by 1. Without Mineguard, 2 mines destroy the Sunderer. Level 1 increases that to 3 mines. Level 2 to 4 mines, etc.    It's essential for the spawn Sunderers since an Engineer with level 1 Anti-Tank mines (100 certs, 2 mines) can instantly blow up a Sunderer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real answer to give you to this. However, I would recommend that you consider at the very minimum getting the spawn upgrade for the Sunderer, it's absolutely vital if you use it, to give you greater power projection (in other words, friendly troops can spawn in the enemy's backyard rather than several kilometres away).

For everything else, it depends how you prefer to play. Squad leader upgrades are helpful if you run groups, but in most other cases it's better to just pick a couple of classes and vehicles to specialise in then focus your certs on upgrades that fit your play style.